# How to exclude certain numbers from autolinking within Android TextView

Tags: android, textview, autolink

I've got a TextView displaying large text in my Android app. The text contains some phone numbers but also some other numbers. The TextView's `autoLink` attribute is set to `ALL`.

At the moment every number that somehow looks like a phone number get's automatically linked regardless whether it is a phone number or not.

So I wonder if there's a way to exclude some of the numbers from auto linking within the same TextView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `autoLink` and instead use [`Linkify`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) with your own `MatchFilter` and `TransformFilter`. You can probably look at the source code to `Linkify` and look at how they are defining `sPhoneNumberTransformFilter` and create your own modified version.

Comment: Thx, I will have a look at it.